# tensorflow-gpu conda environment not working on ubuntu-20.04

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, ubuntu-20.04

I followed the instructions for installing tensorflow on ubuntu 20.04 using *conda* here: [Installing Tensorflow using Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/)

```
conda create --name tf tensorflow-gpu
```

A conda environment was successfully created.  However *tensorflow* with *gpu* does not work:

```
 !18
python3 image_classification_efficientnet_fine_tuning.py
2021-04-25 13:08:58.235320: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-04-25 13:08:58.235341: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image_classification_efficientnet_fine_tuning.py", line 137, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 436, in <module>
    _ll.load_library(_main_dir)
  File "/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 153, in load_library
    py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(lib)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/steve/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/core/kernels/libtfkernel_sobol_op.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK10tensorflow8OpKernel11TraceStringB5cxx11ERKNS_15OpKernelContextEb
```

Getting Tensorflow to install on ubuntu-20.04 with cuda is insanely difficult.

Comment: And that is the hardest part so far. I highly recommend using `pip` to install tensorflow rather than the `conda` package. Please follow the official guideline.

Comment: You can follow [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-gpu-in-ubuntu-20-04-4ee3ca4cb75d).

Comment: @M.Innat  Tried pip many times: including reinstalling entire O/S to give a fresh shot.  It looks like the key may be to choose TF < 2.4.X . I'm trying 2.3.0 now : and the tutorial mentions 2.2.0.   Removing cuda 11.X is troublesome so another fresh O/S install may be needed to ensure only 10.X on there

Answer (score 0):

After creating virtual_environment for `TensorFlow`, you need to install `TensorFlow` in that virtual environment.

```
conda create -n tf-gpu tensorflow-gpu   # to create a virtual environment
conda activate tf-gpu                   # to activate the virtual environment

conda install tensorflow-gpu            # to install tensorflow-gpu
```

**Note:** Please select this `'tf-gpu'` virtual environment in `anaconda` everytime whenever you want to run your `TensorFlow` code.

Try again running your code after executing these above codes and let us know in case issue still persists.